# Why do pygame sprites not work correctly within pygame menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I am using pygame menu and as far as I have found I can't use sprites with pygame menu. I am attempting to make an enemy class similar to galaga or space invaders. However, I can get the enemies to work in a separate file where I don't use pygame menu. I think it has to do with the fact that I'm using a function to start my game but I need to do that in order to have a menu work correctly.

Below is the code of my start function in the file where the enemies do not work correctly.

```
def main_menu():
    menu = pygame_menu.Menu(
        height=900,
        theme=mytheme2,
        title='Galaga',
        width=1400
    )
    menu.add.image(myimage2)
    menu.add.label('Welcome Player One.')
    menu.add.button('Click to start', start)
    menu.add.button('Controls', controls)
    menu.add.button('Rules', rules)
    menu.add.button('Quit the game', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        menu.mainloop(surface)

main_menu()
```

And below here is the enemy class that I made in the file where they do work properly.

```
class Aliens(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("img/alien" + str(random.randint(1, 5)) + ".png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x, y]
        self.move_counter = 0
        self.move_direction = 1

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.move_direction
        self.move_counter += 1
        if abs(self.move_counter) > 75:
            self.move_direction *= -1
            self.move_counter *= self.move_direction



#create Alien Bullets class
class Alien_Bullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("img/alien_bullet.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x, y]

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 2
        if self.rect.top > screen_height:
            self.kill()
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, spaceship_group, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask):
            self.kill()
            explosion2_fx.play()
            #reduce spaceship health
            spaceship.health_remaining -= 1
            explosion = Explosion(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery, 1)
            explosion_group.add(explosion)
```

I have tried to combine the two but it just doesn't function the same way, and I am unsure as to why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with your "start" function. If it is the same, as in this question: [How to make enemies in galaga?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093466), there are several possible errors. First: You call the function

```
clock.tick(40)
```

twice, which is not nessesary.
Also you call your funtions

```
    pause()
    End()
    kill()
    level_increase()
```

in every Game loop. Is that intended?

My recomendation would be to start with a smaler pygame_menu example and then work your way up.
It would also be helpful if your question is a bit more specific about the actual problem you see.